# AnalysisException: Reference 'count' is ambiguous

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

### Given:

**Dataset:**

```
+--------------------+
|               count|
+--------------------+
|                 1.0|
|                 2.0|
|                 3.0|
+--------------------+
```

**Code:**

```
String field = "count";    

Dataset<Row> histogram = dataset
    .groupBy(field)
    .count()
    .persist(StrorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER());

Column cnt = histogram.col("count"); // trying to get .count() result
```

**Histogram schema:**

```
root
 |-- count: double (nullable = true) // input field `count`
 |-- count: long (nullable = false)  // .count() result
```

**Exception:**

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'count' is ambiguous, could be: count#101, count#108L.;
```

### Question:

While I understand, why this happens, I don't have any ideas about how to solve this problem. Dataset is created from a table in the database and may contain any number of columns with any names, including `count`, `avg` and other "reserved" words.

Any help appretiated.

Comment: Could you please provide schema of histogram?

Comment: By changing the column name from "count" to something else? :-P

Comment: @AnuragSharma Sure, I've edited my question.

Comment: @AlexanderRomanov, how about adding some prefix to original columns? for example: `df = df.toDf(*['some_prefix_' + c for c in df.columns])` (please note the this is a pyspark code)

Answer (score 2):

```
dataset.createOrReplaceTempView("V1");
dataset = spark.sql("select count as count_O from v1");
Dataset<Row>  histogram = dataset.groupBy("count_O").count().persist(StrorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER());
Column cnt = histogram.col("count");
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. The problem is that our system is working with thousands of different tables. And it's somewhat difficult to modify our select-queries in that way.